# beamer xparse: optional argument - changing order

Tags: beamer, xparse

Following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812214/latex-optional-arguments I am trying to produce a command that prints a text and optionally sends an argument to a command (well, a time code within the beamer class context).

```
\NewDocumentCommand\mytimecode{ g  m }{%
{   
    \IfNoValueTF {#1}
        {%without optional argument
            \note{#2}
      }
        {%with optional argument
            \note<{#1}>{#2}
        }%
   }%
}
```

So that in a beamer slide's comment I can point to a time code for myself:

```
 \mytimecode{3:30}
```

or show that only on two slides, e.g.

```
\mytimecode{1-2}{3:30}
```

would be a more meaningful syntax/order.

So, how could the required \NewDocumentCommand look like?

Comment: Do you really want to execute `\note{}` twice if there's an optional argument supplied?

Comment: @SergeiGolovan thanks for the question - It made me recognise a problem. now, how to change the order of the arguments? the code above does not work.

Comment: In this case you really don't need any macro, just use `\note{}`. But if you want to then I'd suggest something like `\NewDocumentCommand\mytimecode{D<>{1-}m}{\note<#1>{#2}}` (usage: `\mytimecode{text}` or `\mytimecode<1-2>{text}`)

Comment: thanks again, @SergeiGolovan. Yes that works. if you enter it as an answer, i will accept it. I need a macro to add some more code, that was irrelevant to the problem.